# 3.3v to 5v switch

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, mosfet, logic-level

I'm using a esp8266 which operates at 3.3v logic. I power the board with a 5v power supply dropped to 3.3v on the board. So I have access to both 5v and 3.3v.

I need to make the 3.3v GPIO pin shift to 5v, but also be able to provide 500mA of current. Also, it needs to be limited to 500mA, and provide a input back to a GPIO pin if 500mA is exceeded.

Any of the high switch transistor setups that I have used in the past don't work, as the 3.3v doesn't allow me to open the switch.

For the notification of when it is over current, I was thinking about using a resistor that when the current is 500mA it would turn on another transistor, enabling the GPIO to read high.

I have a lot of transistors and resistors, but only N-MOSFETS.

Thanks!

Comment: This is several questions in one. Try splitting it into one about the logic level shifter and one about the current limit.

Comment: For the voltage:

Get a 5V Schmitt trigger (buffer)  and make sure the Vth High is below 3.3V. 

A current limiter with clip feedback might be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Also, if it can't exceed 500mA it will never provide feedback if it exceeds 500mA....Because it wont (you hope ;))

Comment: @TimMottram Yes true. I meant more along the lines of, if it attempts to draw more than 500mA it will go high.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was being a pedant. :)

Comment: You say you only have N-MOSFETs, but accept an answer suggesting to obtain a custom part. How can I tell which part of your requirements is real an which isn't? -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this part: NCP380.

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP380-D.PDF

It seems to do everything you want and the enable input is 1.2V min, so will easily turn on with your  uC signal.

It has an internal current limit which you can select to be 500mA and a flag output which tells you if there is a load present which would cause the 5V output to try and drive more than this.

EDIT:
The FLAG output is open drain type so put a connect the uC input pin to V+ through a 10k resistor and also to the FLAG output. So when FLAG floats the pin is held to 3.3V and when it's active its connected directly to ground.

Side Note:

The part calls itself a "current limiting power distribution switch" - if this part doesn't meet your spec for some reason, doing searches for that type of part will get you a long way - it's how I found it in the first place with 2 minutes on google.

Comment: Perfect. Solves everything. One question, since I'm just using a single pin for the shifting, an ic shifter seems overkill. Will I be fine just using a diode setup, or should I use transistors to shift the flag?

Comment: Any way you want, you could use a Zener and limiting resistor, two resistors in a simple divider - or there are a wide range of level shifting IC's available, its up to you based on cost reliability etc... Sorry, by divider I meant two resistors, but then you are always wasting some (but not much ) current, like I said, it's all about application.

Answer (score 0):

The FLAG output is open collector, so just add a pullup resistor to 3.3V!

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't look to closely. But I think this should be in the comments not as an answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you're referring to.

Comment: It's the interface the FLAG pin uses, instead of driving a signal high and low, it floats when not active and pulls to ground when active.

Comment: @TimMottram Oh yeah, that make sense. So if EN1 is high, then OUT1 will have power? Then EN2/OUT2 are unused? I wonder if it works 3.3v logic.. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Are you looking at the part on the data sheet? There is only one EN. But you are correct, when EN is low out is 0v and when high Out is 5V and can supply 500mA. As long as EN is above 1.2v Out will be on.

Comment: @TimMottram Oh sorry, was looking at NCP382.. Thanks again. That ends my question streak with you :)

Comment: np, hope you get there. :)